# DuckDuckGo: Exact string search within a domain

Tags: search, duckduckgo

I searched DuckDuckGo for [site:wikipedia.org "advisary"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3awikipedia.org%20%22advisary%22), hoping to spot some typos.

To my surprise, DuckDuckGo replied with articles that do not contain the word "advisary", even thought I took the pain to put it inside quotes.

I notice that this behavior [only](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22andherenoresults%22) occurs in conjunction with the usage of the `site:` keyword.

How to search for an exact string within a domain with DuckDuckGo?

Comment: I have tested and it also occurs if you add a space at the end of the exact string:

Comment: ...the exact string: ["advisary "](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22advisary+%22). I have submitted a bug report at dukgo.com

Comment: @TomHorwood: Thanks a lot! Could you tell us the URL of the bug report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This help page explains the situation best:](https://dukgo.com/help/en_US/results/autocorrect)

> Our intention is to not auto-correct searches. That is, we intend to
>   completely respect the query you type in, and (in some cases) display
>   a 'Did you mean?' link at the top when relevant.
>
> However, there are a few outstanding major bugs in this area that we
>   are working to resolve. As a result, you may see some auto-correct
>   behavior in the search results.
>
> Unfortunately, these bugs involve a bunch of APIs that are mostly out
>   of our control. We are both working around these bugs and also working
>   to get them fixed .
>
> For some queries, it has been a little slow to resolve, but rest
>   assured that this is a top priority. In any case, specific examples
>   always help as we may be able to easily add more workarounds.

(Thanks for the specific example!)

I'm David from the DuckDuckGo team - if you want proof, e-mail me at david (at sign) duckduckgo.com.

Comment: Hello! Has this been fixed? I have today tried to search "(-1)^x" and it gave me absolutely irrelevant results!